# Turn multiple youtube/vimeo links into embedded players

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube

So im trying to convert multiple links into youtube / vimeo embed iframes.

It seems to work for a single video inside of the messageText div, but when I add multiple videos, the link breaks.

[Heres a JSFiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rb5H/1/)

```
<div class="messageText"> 
LOOK AT ME!!! youtube.com/watch?v=8tv-e9DJqK4 youtube.com/watch?v=8tv-e9DJqK4    youtube.com/watch?v=8tv-e9DJqK4
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.messageText').html(function(i, html) {

address = html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videoPlayer" ></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<iframe id="videoPlayer" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');    
alert(address);
return address;
});
});
 </script>
```

Like I said, im trying to get any youtube, vimeo link to convert to the embeded player, no matter what amount of videos are in the div. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are using a greedy operator and what you are capturing is not right , a little modification to your regex will do the trick :

use this

```
(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.*?)([^\s]+)
```

however, you actually dont need to right such a long regex, you can use lookaheads instead. For the time being this will work for you..

similarly you can figure out for vimeo also :)

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3Rb5H/2/

cheers !

Comment: thanks @aelor, this is def. much more cleaner! Im not that familiar with regex is why.

Comment: @ThelsonRichardson you might want to learn regex quickly, here is a website that helped me learn regexone

Comment: won't be okay if the url is "html inserted", like `<p>youtube.com/watch?v=8tv-e9DJqK4</p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.*?)([^\s]+)/g, '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videoPlayer" ></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<iframe id="videoPlayer" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```