# Adjust youtube url to embed parser to remove extras

Tags: php, regex

I have this php code to turn youtube urls into videos automatically:

```
    $search = '%
    (?:https?://)?
    (?:www\.)?
    (?:
      youtu\.be/
    | youtube\.com
      (?:
        /embed/
      | /v/
      | /watch\?v=
      | /watch\?feature=player_embedded&v=
      )
    )
    ([\w\-]{10,12})
    \b
    %x';

    $replace = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" width=\"550\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1\" data-youtube-id=\"$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

return preg_replace($search, $replace, $url);
```

What would be the easiest way to strip out anything after the video id?

Comment: please provide an example of the output you trying to achieve

Comment: the one you are using is the best way. This is considering almost all cases of youtube urls you can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218718/get-youtube-id-for-all-url-types

Comment: you may want to take a look at this regex : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678658/turn-multiple-youtube-vimeo-links-into-embedded-players/22679105#22679105

Comment: @Sharky, the output is in there, it's the $replace...

Comment: When trying to get a part of a URL I always try using php's `parse_url`, in some cases it is more robust than a regexp.

Comment: @Chevi can't use that when it's part of a larger body of text.

Comment: @LiamDawe I didn't realize that from your question, you can always use a normal url regex parser, which usually work great, and then run `parse_url` to get the parameter. Might be easier

Comment: Try parsing `http://youtube.com/v/?foo=bar&v=baz` with a regex, where foo can be anything. There are many other cases where the regex can fail, just putting this here for whoever downvoted my answer. @Chevi's suggestion works much better than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also - I realize you can eventually get a regex to work with the example above, the problem is getting it to work with all other examples, whichever they may be.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. The suggested link actually links to another regex. Use `parse_url` and `parse_str`, that's what they're there for, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15218823/470877). Parsing URLs with regex [is hard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-50) and there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm not putting in a link directly, but grabbing it from a larger body of text so I cannot just parse_url it.

Comment: @LiamDawe - alright, that makes more sense, can you please mention that in your question? I would still suggest a "lighter" regex for finding the URL and then using parse_url, but that's your call really. Depending on where you find the URL you'll probably need to match more than `\?v=` and `\?feature=...&v=` for example and you'd need to change your regex accordingly. `/v/?foo=bar&v=` is also a valid youtube URL.

Comment: Added my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way thanks to others links, here's a function to search a body of text and replace all youtube links with videos:

```
function youtube($body)
{   
    $video_pattern = '~(?:http|https|)(?::\/\/|)(?:www.|)(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=|\/ytscreeningroom\?v=|\/feeds\/api\/videos\/|\/user\S*[^\w\-\s]|\S*[^\w\-\s]))([\w\-]{11})[a-z0-9;:@#?&%=+\/\$_.-]*~i';

    preg_match_all($video_pattern, $body, $matches);
    //print_r($matches[0]);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $url)
    {
        if (strpos($url, 'feature=youtu.be') == TRUE || strpos($url, 'youtu.be') == FALSE ) 
        {
            parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $id);
            $id = $id['v'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $id = basename($url);
        }

        $body = str_replace($url, "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" width=\"550\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$id}\" data-youtube-id=\"{$id}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $body);
    }

    return $body;
}
```